# Parse Query Not Calling Where

Tags: objective-c, sdk, parse-platform

For some reason, the where key in my parse query does not seem to work.

```
    NSString *uploaderId = [object[@"Uploader"] valueForKey:@"objectId"];

    PFQuery *findLikes = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activity"];
    [findLikes whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"Like"];
    [findLikes whereKey:@"from" equalTo:uploaderId];
    [findLikes findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Amount of likes for cell: %lu", (unsigned long)objects.count);
    }];
```

The count is 0 even though there is an item in the Activity table.

To clarify, from is a pointer for a specific user.

Also, I want to display the first four likers of the photo, in different labels. How would I do this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    FeedTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[FeedTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle     reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    PFQuery * findLikes = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activity"];
    [findLikes includeKey:@"from"];
    [findLikes includeKey:@"recapId"];
    [findLikes whereKey:@"from" equalTo:object[@"Uploader"]];
    [findLikes whereKey:@"recapId" equalTo:object];
    [findLikes whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"Like"];
    [findLikes findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Amount of likes for cell: %lu", (unsigned long)objects.count);
        for (PFObject *likers in objects) {
            cell.liker.text = [[likers objectForKey:@"from"] valueForKey:@"name"];
        }
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a relational query, so you can either use the object itself (that appears to be object[@"Uploader"])...

```
PFQuery *findLikes = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Activity"];
[findLikes whereKey:@"from" equalTo:object[@"Uploader"]];
// plus your other criterion
```

Or, if you'd rather use the id...

```
[findLikes whereKey:@"from"
            equalTo:[PFObject objectWithoutDataWithClassName:@"User" objectId:uploaderId]];
```

But I think the first way is simpler.

**EDIT** - Regarding the table view problem.  `cellForRowAtIndexPath` isn't a good place for an asynch query.  That gets run again and again every time a cell comes into view.  The right pattern is to create a model for the table view, which is an array of Activity objects.

```
@property(strong,nonatomic) NSArray *activityArray;
```

Someplace early, like `viewWillAppear`:, do the query once and initialize the array with the result, then tell your table view about it:

```
// viewWilAppear
[findLikes findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    // if no error ...
    self.activityArray = objects;  
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];
```

Then your datasource:

```
// in cellForRowAtIndexPath
PFObject *liker = self.activityArray[indexPath.row];
cell.liker.text = [[liker objectForKey:@"from"] valueForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: Thank you. I am running into a seperate issue having to do with my cells. Do you think you could help me a little further?

Comment: sure.  if this one gets you the data, maybe mark it correct and post a table view question?

Comment: I can only post every 90 minutes. Do you have a skype / can I simply edit this post after marking your answer?

Comment: sorry , no way to Skype at the moment.  Maybe edit the question as a two-parter.  Please don't edit your current parse code to match my suggestion.  Leave it as is and just add a question about presenting results.  (Make sure it's not answered elsewhere on SO)

Comment: Hey - I solved that problem actually using the same way ;) - The problem I'm running into now is I just want to show the first four likers in 4 different labels on my cell. How would I do that instead?

Comment: I'd just build an array of the likers' names when the data arrives.  You can grab the first MIN(array.count, 3) and use an array method componentsJoinedByString:@", ".  Then put that into a single label.

Comment: What about if I wanted to do images, like for their avatars instead of names.

Comment: That's a bigger question than comments can handle.  You'll need N views and N asycnh requests for those images, cacheing, etc.  I'd get the basics working and come back to that.